# Modify clipboard shortcuts on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

On macOS, the clipboard shortcuts are `⌘+C`, `⌘+V`, and `⌘+X`.

How can I change them to use the **CTRL** modifier key instead of the **CMD** modifier key: `⌃+C`, `⌃+V`, and `⌃+X`?

In Mac SystemSettings, there is an option to REMAP (!) the Modifier Keys (here from a German Mac):

[image]

But that would change **ALL** keyboard shortcuts where the CONTROL key is used! Of course, I do not want that!

Comment: Giving discouraging counsel is a negative social attitude. It is against the human principle of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ADD your own APP SHORTCUTS:

[image]

macOS Monterey 12.01 German version:

[image]

Comment: It works properly on my computer.